# Querying Android Gmail database only returns current emails loaded

Tags: java, android, database, email

Working on an app that accesses Gmails stored within Androids databases. Querying

> gmail-ls/conversations/EMAIL_ADDRESS

only returns emails that are currently loaded within Gmail, which makes sense. The only way I have found to get more is to physically scroll to the bottom of the list within the Gmail app.

Is there a way to get hold of all the users emails using that database, or is this something best handled through JavaMail etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Working on an app that accesses Gmails stored within Androids databases.

There are no "Gmails stored within Androids databases". There is no email support within the Android OS or SDK.

> is this something best handled through JavaMail etc?

Yes.

Comment: There are emails in the database, I am printing them out, maybe it is not recommended? When I load more conversations, then more are shown within the database. I query it exactly as I do with text messages.

Comment: @Christopher Gwilliams: Android is an operating system. Android does not have databases of emails or text messages. You are hacking into other applications, using undocumented and unsupported means. You have been told by Google not to do this (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html). Your code will crash on various devices, where those apps do not exist or have been altered. Your code will be ineffective on devices where users are using other applications for GMail and/or SMS. What makes you think that any of this is a good idea?

Comment: I am not making this for financial purposes, and I am aware of the warnings against it. I know people that have forgotten passwords and do not have access to gmail, aside from their phone, so I am making an app that forwards all of these emails.
Its not a good idea, but it is the only solution for those people, so it is the only logical idea.